# Creating users and assigning passwords on linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am creating multiple users (this case 3 users) on a linux bash script using the line

```
sudo adduser --force-badname  CPE_User"$count"
```

and I am trying to give those users a password that I assign in the script using:

```
echo "CPE_User"$count":1234" | chpasswd
```

but the terminal gives me this message :

```
Allowing use of questionable username.
adduser: The user `CPE_User1' already exists.
Changing password for CPE_User1.
chpasswd: (user CPE_User1) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user CPE_User1) password not changed
```

What is the problem?

Comment: are you running this script as root? chpasswd for another user needs root privileges (so if you're calling sudo on adduser, you most likely want to call sudo on chpasswd too, or better - on the whole script).

Answer (score 1):

It says it quite clearly: a user with that name already exists. Linux doesn't allow to have more than one user with the same name...

Comment: it says that, but there is not a user with the same name :/

Comment: well, there probably *is* another user by that name. You've probably tried running the script several times, and it has already created all these users, however it has failed changing their passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `chpasswd` problem might be (you are running it as `root`, right?) If you can't get `chpasswd` to work, consider using `passwd` (potentially via an `expect` script) - that will work for sure.